# How to add a <form > tag dynamically to the li items of an ul that are also being created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

A JavaScript function to repeat `ul` i dynamically with `<input>` inside it:

```
function createEditableLi(ulId) {
    const ul = document.getElementById(ulId);
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const newinput = document.createElement("input");
    newinput.setAttribute("class", "input_style");
    newinput.setAttribute("id", "textboxId");
    newinput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newinput.setAttribute("name", "card_name");
    newLi.setAttribute("id", "editableLi");
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
    newLi.appendChild(newinput);
}
```

and it creates html as

```
<li id="editableLi">
  <input name="card_name" type="text" id="textboxId" class="input_style" />
</li>
```

but I want my html to be like this with javascript

```
<form action="./card-controller-task-pending" method="POST">
  <li id="editableLi">
    <input name="card_name" type="text" id="textboxId" class="input_style" />
  </li>
</form>
```

Comment: You can only have `<ul>` around li-elements. Do you want to have something like `<form> <ul> <li> ... </li> </ul> </form>`  ?

Comment: You can't have a `<form>` inside the `<ul>` The list can only have list items as children. You could put the form inside the `<li>` though. And now you know that fact, it shouldn't be hard to achieve. It's clear you already know how to add the list item and the input element. You can follow the same process to create the form. Attach the form to the `<li>`, then attach the input element to the form. Try that. If you get stuck, post your updated code and a description of the error/problem.

Comment: P.S. When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" isn't a question. And "how to" is generally too vague. This isn't a tutorial site or free write-my-code service. We'll _help_ you to work with _your attempt_ at solving the problem, and improve/fix it for you, or answer a specific question about the code. In general, unless it's trivial, you'll find people aren't keen to just do it all for you, without some evidence of effort on your own part.

Comment: Okay got it guys, thank you for response

Answer (score 0):

I started to answer but @ADyson comment it well, anyway - this would be the general approach:

```js
function createEditableLi() {
    const container = document.getElementById('demo');
    const newForm = document.createElement("form");
    newForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
    newForm.setAttribute("action", "URL"); // change this
    const newUl = document.createElement("ul");
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    newLi.setAttribute("id", "editableLi");
    const newinput = document.createElement("input");
    newinput.setAttribute("class", "input_style");
    newinput.setAttribute("id", "textboxId");
    newinput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newinput.setAttribute("name", "card_name");

    newLi.appendChild(newinput);
    newUl.appendChild(newLi);
    newForm.appendChild(newUl);
    container.appendChild(newForm);
}
createEditableLi();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this wraps a form around the whole list. OP didn't make clear if there should be a separate form for each list item, or one overall form. The implication is one form per list item (since the original code doesn't create a new list). Although since there's no requirement given for a way to submit the form, it's not 100% clear.